# Xamarin.Forms previewer freezes Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with the Xamarin.forms previewer in Visual Studio 2015 (Enterprise).
When I open the previewer in Visual Studio, VS freezes for a really long time and like after a minute it unfreezes and shows the previewer.

But afterwards VS is really really slow. And continues to freeze. 
I have a quite good computer with core i7 and 16gb ram so it shouldn't be the problem.

Does anyone else have this issue?

Has anybody fixed this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once i connected to the mac with MAC Agent everything started working without delay.

Comment: Ha! Same here. That's why it worked really well when I'm at work (Mac connected), but when I worked from home it started to get really slow.

Answer (score 1):

**Xamarin.Forms' XAML Previewer** for **Visual Studio 2015** is really buggy. This happened to me a couple of times before, but I switched to **Visual Studio 2017** and it's so much better. I'd suggest you also switch to 2017, because they really took the time to improve XAML Previewer.

Answer (score 0):

Currently experiencing the same problem. Cleaning installation of windows and vs 2017 enterprise. If i open a xmal page without the previewer pages will load fast and normal. But if i have the previewer open VS will freeze for about 1 1/2 mintues